# java jar Error: Unable to access from command line

Tags: java, jar

I cant execute java jar file from cmd windows 10.
I have generated a jar file using Intellji.

when I run the command Java -jar  I got this error

Error: Unable to access jarfile

I tried running the cmd with administration right but same error. the class path is set correctly. the jar file is located in the right directory .

What could be causing the problem?
Thank you

Comment: what is the name of your jar file?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you use

```
java -jar TestJar.jar
```

instead of

```
java -jar TestJar
```

If this is not your error, the file might not exist or you don´t have permission to open it.

Comment: I tried this doesn't work as well, the file does exist!